# how can I hide a text by referring to a CSS class or id?

Tags: jquery

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("span").click(function(){
            $(.comment).hide();
          });
        });
        </script>

       <a class=".comment">comment</a>'<br/><span class="comment">&bull;<a style="padding-left:3.5px;" href ="">Comment</a></span><form align="left" id="bring" action="profile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="blab_from">
<textarea name="blab_field" rows="3" style="width:100%; height:30px;"></textarea>
 <input id="bringinput" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" align="left" />
</form></td>
```

how can I hide the "&bull comment" text and make the form appear with that jquery?

Comment: just the <span><a>comment</a></span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have wrong class definition at  tag (don't use a dot)

use this  `<a class="comment">comment</a>`

Comment: thanks now I want to make the form appear when the comment text hide. I want to say there is a lot of code above and below that's not the only thing, and I only want to make the comment text hide and form appear. Just like the jquery comment script here at stackoverflow any input?

Comment: just put all form code into `<div class="commentForm">...your code...</div>` and change jQuery code to this `$('.comment').hide().next('.commentForm').show();`

Comment: where can I find the jquery.js document I need it I think the one Is not working I am not sure if it is good where can I find the jquery.js

Comment: Janovcik it is showing the form when the comment text is show I want to show the comment text only and then after clicking then show the commentForm

Comment: the text hide but just for 2 seconds then it comes back to the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Remove dot(.) in class attribute and then try.

```
<a class="comment">comment</a>
```

Comment: thanks now I want to make the form appear when the comment text hide. I want to say there is a lot of code above and below that's not the only thing, and I only want to make the comment text hide and form appear. Just like the jquery comment script here at stackoverflow any input?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
<a class=".comment">comment</a>
```

to this:

```
<a class="comment">comment</a>
```

but keep your jQuery javascript the same.

The dot in front of comment tells jQuery to look for a class named *comment*, not .comment.

Comment: thanks now I want to make the form appear when the comment text hide. I want to say there is a lot of code above and below that's not the only thing, and I only want to make the comment text hide and form appear. Just like the jquery comment script here at stackoverflow any input?